# Wordpress WooCommerce : Showing recent and random products on same page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I am using woocommerce for my online store. I want to show 20 most recent products from a category and then random products of same category on same page. Actually I don't want my old products to hide. When I use two shortcodes on same page nothing is displayed but separately both shortcodes work fine. I searched over the internet and found nothing. Please help

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort from newest to oldest in your archive (since not specified, this is my guess) or somewhere else, just add this code to your functions.php

```
    add_filter(‘woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args’,‘am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby’);
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
$args[‘meta_key’] = ‘_price’;
$args[‘orderby’] = ‘meta_value_num’;
$args[‘order’] = ‘desc’;
return $args;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I want to do is to show 20 recent products and then random products. I have added your code in function.php but nothing. I think its only for recent products. See the attached image to get an idea of what I really want to do.

Comment: Let me send you a screenshot

Comment: order it by desc and not by rand